# Does Anivia's Frostbite synergize with other Champions?

Tags: league-of-legends

Frostbite deals double damage to champions "slowed by an ice effect." This seems to imply that any ice effect should work, but the forums seem divided on the matter.

It obviously works with Anivia's own skills, as otherwise it would be pointless. Check off Flash Frost, and Glacial Storm.

Very few people seem to think that the damage doubles against champions effected by items. Items that seem to slow via frost are Rylai's Crystal Scepter, and Iceborn Gauntlet.

There are a number of champions with ice-based slows, and this list seems more divisive, some threads seem to claim a subset, some claim them all, and some claim none of them. Those I can think of are:

1. Sejuani; Frost, Permafrost
2. Ashe; Frost Shot, Volley (sometimes), Enchanted Crystal Arrow
3. Nunu; Ice blast, Absolute Zero

Comment: I'm quite sure it procs only on Anivia's Flash Frost and Glacial Storm, and Ashe's Enchanted Crystal Arrow.

Comment: Cassadins poison fangs do prox with Teemo's poison darts, which make them a cool combo :P

Comment: In all honesty I play Anivia fairly regularly, but it is rather rare for me to have a Sejuani, Nunu, or even an Ashe on my team. I could get a couple friends together next time I play and test this, but it will probably be a day or so before I will be able to post again. In all honesty I think they all probably synergize with her E. But the effect time on most of them is very small meaning for most you would need the E on its way already as the skill strikes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Lol wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Anivia)

> "ACTIVE: Anivia fires a shard of ice to deal magic damage to a target enemy. Frostbite deals double damage to enemies "chilled" by Anivia's other spells."

Anivia's E does not deal double damage to enemies "chilled" by Ashe's Arrow, but rather only enemies chilled by Anivia's own spells.
In the past, Anivia synergized with other sources of chill, but these interactions have since been patched out.

Comment: Do you have any source other than the wiki thread? I had come across that, but wasn't sure where that information came from. Sadly the talk page isn't being used.

Comment: Why did they removed this interactions :-(. I remember before it was working even with the Rylai's Crystal Scepter. Other subject cassiopea's fangs works with teemo and singed

Comment: @Sconibulus I am sorry I looked a bit this afternoon. I cannot find any other reliable sources that confirm Frostbite's interaction with Enchanted Crystal Arrow. LoL wiki is usually pretty accurate though it may require in game testing to be sure.

Comment: @AdamP - Note that the wiki was not including this part about Ashe's arrow until recently, and without more details than that: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/index.php?title=Anivia&diff=1661587&oldid=1661024

Comment: I remember it having synergy with Sejuani's abilities (henceforth known as Pigbitch), but it was taken out due to balance issues. This was likely the case with Rylai's. I am not sure why they would keep the interaction with Ashe's ult if they deemed all other forms of frost overpowered in the situation.

Comment: @Sconibulus ok sorry it took so long. My roommate and I got down and did some serious testing on the subject. Anivia's E only works for HER SPELLS. It does not synergize with any other type of chill currently in the game.